# Please help me in Installation of ROS. I have to make localization of corobot

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i setup exe of ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199161/please-help-me-in-installation-of-ros.-i-have-to-make-localization-of-corobot./) by [ayana](https://answers.ros.org/users/21064/ayana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start with Ubuntu install of ROS Indigo [here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)

Exept ubuntu other are experimental doesnt provide complete packages.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0